# TFS Workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I want to delete a workspace from another user different than mine How can I do this? If I use Visual Studio 2008 integration, I can only manage my own workspaces, but I cant see other users workspaces. I guess that one option should be connecting to the server with a different user in visual studio, but I cant find that option. Visual studio uses my windows username to login, so I cant see the login dialog. Any ideas?

Thanks

Federico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the command line tool `TF.EXE` (use the Visual Studio command line to get it in your path).

```
tf help workspace
```

To list the options, and more detailed help on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As well as the command line (tf.exe) you can also do this with the excellent and free [TFS SideKicks from Attrice](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) if command lines are not your thing.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a simular issue a while back and here is the way I fixed it.  We had a person leave the company and they had a bunch of files locked.

Here is the command list of what I did... 
I have a blog post (link at the bottom) that gives a detailed replay of what my fix was.

1. tf workspaces /computer:ComputerName
   /owner:* /format:detailed
   /server:http://teamserver01:8080
2. tf workspace /delete
   /server:http://teamserver01:8080
   ComputerName;TheOtherGuy
3. yes
4. tf workspaces /computer:ComputerName
   /owner:* /format:detailed
   /server:http://teamserver01:8080

[YetAnotherDeveloper.com](http://yetanotherdeveloper.com/post/2007/12/12/How-to-remove-roguezombie-workspaces-from-TeamServer.aspx)

Comment: Please note that "TheOtherGuy" will need to be the users actual domain user name and not the name that is typically displayed when running the tf workspaces command.  An example: We have user Bob W. Jones. On the domain hosting TFS named WorkDomain, his actual username is jonesbw despite the fact that the tf workspaces command shows him as "Bob W. Jones".  His workspace name is BJWorkspace.  The command you will need to run is tf workspace /delete /server:http://teamserver01:8080 BJWorkspace;Workdomain\jonesbw